# Android app stops after start on Amazon Kindle Fire HD

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, kindle-fire

I've got Android app which runs on various devices, but not Amazon Kindle Fire HD.
It stops after start and what I see in the logs is following:

```
08:42:16.940    201 #201    WARN    ActivityManager Unable to start service Intent { act=com.amazon.client.metrics.bind }: not found
08:42:17.104    201 #201    WARN    ActivityManager   Force finishing activity com.example/.MyActivity
```

Anybody knows what this could be and if those two warnings are related?

Comment: hm, so I made a simple Hello world test project and targeted it to Amazon platform and run it. It works, but I see the same warning in logs about not able to start service Intent, so that makes me think that those two are not in relation and there is something else wrong in the app.

Comment: another thing, I don't even see my logs from onCreate, so app seems to be finished very early.

Comment: swapping existing activity with some simple Hello World activity helps, so there must something fishy in code or layout what Amazon device doesn't like. I'll post my findings when I get to it.

Comment: Amazon has modified something :)

Comment: OK, so the problem is deprecated class KeyguardLock and calling lock.disableKeyguard(); which makes the app stop. Deprecated since API 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the correct answer how to solve this issue:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html

Answer (score 0):

and it is not only deprecated, it is not supported by Amazon.
To comply with Amazon requirements, please read this page:
https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html#AppFeature